# getMultiCapabilities not working with arrow function

Tags: configuration, protractor

getMultiCapabilities seems not working with arrow function. So I defined 'getMultiCapabilities' function rather than 'multiCapabilities' property in the protractor config.ts like this:

```
    export let config: Config = {
        ...
        getMultiCapabilities: () => { // this doesn't work;
            ...                 // replacing it with "function() {" is okay
        },
        beforeLaunch: () => { // this works fine
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
```

This results in "Error: Debug Failure. False expression: position cannot precede the beginning of the file". Replacing arrow with 'function' works fine. Is this a protractor bug? or did I miss something?

Comment: You will need to provide some more info. Can you post more of your configuration file? What version of node/typescript are you using?

Comment: node --version says "v6.10.0", and npm list typescript says "typescript@2.1.5"

Comment: And I don't know which part of protractor configuration you need to know. Probably could you let me know what else you need to get? Thanks